# Magento2 custom theme isnt loading parent files

Tags: themes, parent, magento2, custom-theme

I have created new custom theme

when I try to load frontend, I got errors about missing files >

```
pub/static/frontend/Vendor/lumaDark/en_GB/mage/calendar.css 
pub/static/frontend/Vendor/lumaDark/en_GB/css/styles-m.css 
pub/static/frontend/Vendor/lumaDark/en_GB/requirejs/require.js 
pub/static/frontend/Vendor/lumaDark/en_GB/css/styles-l.css 
pub/static/frontend/Vendor/lumaDark/en_GB/mage/requirejs/mixins.js 
requirejs-config.js:66 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a     function(anonymous function) @ requirejs-config.js:66(anonymous function)     @ requirejs-config.js:71(anonymous function) @ requirejs-config.js:601
(index):27 Uncaught TypeError: require.config is not a     function(anonymous function) @ (index):27
(index):156 GET     pub/static/frontend/Vendor/lumaDark/en_GB/images/logo.svg 404 (Not Found)
    (index):18 GET                pub/static/frontend/Vendor/lumaDark/en_GB/css/print.css
```

folder structure

```
app
-design
--frontend
---Vendor
----lumaDark
-----Magento_Theme
------layout
-------default_head_blocks.xml
-----etc
------view.xml
-----media
------preview.jpg
-----web
------fonts
------images
------js
-----composer.json
-----registration.php
-----theme.xml
```

I am in developer mode. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I shall give the answer to this since asking a dead topic if there was an answer yet is apparently abusing.

First of all this topic belongs in the magento stack exchange (better to correct that)

Second i had the same issue and solved it by placing a logo.svg in the web/images folder. For some reason Magento 2 does not like not having a basic logo and won't inherit that from the parent.

After i had added the logo.svg (and the preview.jpg in the media folder) all the other things got loaded fine and i did not have any JS or CSS errors.

Let me know if this worked for you.